# WordPress - passing form values to a download manager

Tags: php, pdf, wordpress

**CONTEXT**

We are creating a Wordpress site that allows users to log-in, select a resource, fill out a form, and then download a PDF that is stamped with the information filled out on the form. We are currently using the [Wordpress Content Manager](http://www.wpdownloadmanager.com/) plugin on a Genesis child theme to manage downloads. This plugin has the functionality to control access to files, make a download button conditional on filling out a form and stamp a PDF with static information about the user. The workflow should look like this:

1. User selects resource from a list
2. User is taken to a form and fills it out
3. On form submission, user is taken to a download page where a download link for this resource's PDF is available
4. The PDF is downloaded, stamped with information that the user filled out on the form in the previous step.

**PROBLEM**

We would like to pass information from the form to the PDF stamper. However, there is not native functionality that allows this. The plugin is limited to stamping information that is in the user's profile. We are wondering what the simplest way of passing data from a form back to the plugin might be.

Comment: Just store the other data in wp_usermeta table. and call it out in stamper

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @VaibhavBhanushali. Just to be clear - a single user can download the same file multiple times and each download instance needs to be stored as a unique entry in the DB. Does it make sense to do this in wp_usermeta or to create a new table that contains download instances?

Comment: Well, i would prefer native WordPress system, instead of creating a table.
Usermeta can be easily be accessed/modified and is quicker as compared to doing it with Sql query.